# MySQL with PDO Statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What is wrong with the following code, because my data is missing, and there are returned records :

```
     $db_stmt = new PDOStatement();
    $db_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id_translation AS ID, content AS Label FROM ?");        
    $language = "language_translation_" . $request->request_object->language; 
    $db_stmt->bindParam(1, $language);        
    $db_stmt->execute();        
    while ($obj = $db_stmt->fetchObject()){
        $response->response_list[] = $obj;
        unset($obj);
    }
```

Edit :
    I am creating a web service to get some data from a mysql database.
   I test my service with a rest client. (I don't need to echo !!!)

Comment: Why is `unset($obj)` inside `while`?

Comment: to unset the current obj. commented or not i still don't get my data.

Comment: Yes, I thought so much. But if you unset it inside a loop, it could be the source of the problem. Try moving it after the `while`.

Comment: i commented that and my data is still missing.

Comment: Where do you `echo` or do something else with the results? (Or does `$response->response_list[]` do it automatically?)

Comment: this is a web service.  please vote my question because is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: i did not understood what you said. "var dumping the result" = ??

Comment: @rhose87: put var_dump($obj) right inside the while loop. Check whether you are getting something from the **$obj = $db_stmt->fetchObject()** execution.

Comment: As i mentioned in my edit part : i test my service with a rest client. with or without put_dump($obj) the result is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you cannot bind a parameter to a table name. please try something like

```
$db_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id_translation AS ID, content AS Label FROM `$language`");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Be careful with this kind of code. It provides an access point for SQL Injections. Make sure you properly escape and quote all your identifiers.  There is no way built into PDO to do this for you.

Comment: i edited to addslashes($language) and it's all fine. thanks a lot for your answers.